# jQuery slideUp toggle close last div

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slideup

I've got this http://jsfiddle.net/jv4ae32j/ toggle script working just the way I want it apart from one thing I want yo close the div when the last title is clicked

```
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
      $('aside').slideUp();
      $(this).find('aside').slideToggle();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('aside')` will target all the elements with classde. you need to filter out the aside inside clicked element.Like this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('aside').not($(this).find('aside')).slideUp();
    $(this).find('aside').slideToggle();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gcqbxyhk/)**